# is it possible to create a vertical line without it being able to change size when the window is reduced?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Everything is in the title. You can have an example below. Is it because I'm using wrongfully `top`, `left` and `bottom`?

```css
div.line {
    width:4px;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top:180px;
    bottom:400px;
    left:130px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cordially

Comment: `min-height` ??

Comment: `top:180px; bottom:400px;` if the height is equal to 580px or less ... there is no room to  lay anything out. ;) look for another method to draw that line that will allow you to set fixed size.

Comment: Thanks @LouysPatriceBessette, I've forgot this...

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.line {
    width:4px;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The preview-window is too small to display your line. With your code it has a margin of 180px to the top and a margin of 40px to the bottom. I changed your code to make the line visible. Is that the way you wanted the line to look like?

Answer (score 0):

The `top` and `bottom` relative position are in fact defining a relative `height`.

You can add a `min-height` to it... Which may override the `bottom` positionning.

```css
div.line {
    width:4px;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top:180px;
    bottom:400px;
    left:130px;
    
    min-height: 580px; /* Add the value you want here */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```